# pympress video howto

Tags: video

Using beamer and pdfLaTeX under Linux, I would like to present an included video with pympress. Currently I am including videos with

```
\fullFrameMovie[]{myvideo.mp4}{img.png}
```

but I cannot start the video from my pympress presentation.

Does anybody have a working example?
Thx, Karl

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution while I was looking for a complete code example as requested by Stefan. Beamers multimedia package does what I want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \movie[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img.png}}{video.mp4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In pympress, when I use this code and  I click on the frame with video (a mp4), I get video play controls, but pressing the play button does nothing.  This does not work for me.

Comment: The example of kjo works for me.... but only after I installed `python-vlc` (VLC was already installed) - a dependency I had missed from the `pympress` GitHub page. `pip install python-vlc` might fix your problems